# Principal local Artinian ring is a quotient of discrete valuation ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I have seen [here](https://www.imj-prg.fr/~christophe.cornut/ES/Ref/KolySys.pdf%E2%80%8E) the following statement:

Let $R$ be a principal local Artinian ring. Clearly the quotient of a discrete valuation ring is such a ring; conversely it is not difficult to show that every principal local artinian ring is a quotient of a discrete valuation ring.

But there was no proof there. Does anyone know the proof or a reference?
(At least for the case of perfect residue field of characteristic $p$ which I am interested in especially.)

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25663/elementary-proof-wanted-every-local-principal-ideal-ring-is-a-quotient-of-a-pid

Comment: Dear @user26857, thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I want!!